# Web API that itself sends data to client on availability

Tags: django, web, publish-subscribe

I am currently working with Django but I am stuck as I don't know if I am pursuing the right model given the nature of my application.

**Problem Statement:**

I have to make a REST API for a client such that whenever I get a trigger for a new entry/entries in my Database I have to send those to the client which is supposed to listen to a URL and has asked for data only once and now is open to receive data whenever available to him.
It is **not** sending a GET request now and then.

There will be different endpoints of the APIs. One is where I provide him all the new data available to me and in other where it asks for specific data (ex: '/myAPI/givemethis')

I can easily implement the second requirement as it is a simple request-response case.

I am not sure how to send him data that too on availability without him making a repeated request as client.

It appears a Publisher-Subscriber model is better suited for my use case but I don't know how to implement it on Django.
I bumped into several concepts like StreamingServices and MQTT but I am not sure what should be the right choice to go with.

Kindly provide some suggestions.

Comment: easy way is to trigger ajax calls to api in time interval to chcek if there is something new. harder way is to use websokets(django-channels). in second aproche you use signal to send to ws channel message with new objects(or whatever you need). the first aproche at some point will generate many calls to api (with growing users nuber)

Comment: I read django-channels use ASGI mode for communication. Would I be able to use WSGI base communication along with ASGI or is it not required for me to worry about this?
I just don't want to disturb my other endpoints.

Comment: I'm using asgi and wsgi at the same time. it took me a while to make it run on production. im using mix of Apache2 and daphne